# Doc2Vec vs Avg Word Vectors : Which is better for Sentiment Analysis?

Tags: nlp, word2vec, sentiment-analysis, doc2vec

I was performing Sentiment Analysis on the IMdb dataset on Kaggle. I used the BOW approach with bigrams and that gave me a decent accuracy of ~89%. But I dont know how to approach the same using word embeddings: Should i go for averaged word vectors or doc2vec?

Someone please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [recent blog post](https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-text-classification-model-comparison-and-selection-5eb066197568) comparing word2vec averaging vs doc2vec performance. The post favors doc2vec. It also depends on what classification model you are using (logistic regression, SVM, LSTM, etc.)

Comment: Thanks. It was quite helpful.